# Classgraph dependency on Javers require JDK9+

Tags: spring, maven, javers

I'm using Javers Spring integration inside my application. I have a problem with Javers'es dependency named `classgraph` - it requires JDK9 while in my project I use Java 8 and unfortunately I'm not able to bump it to the `9`.

Has anyone met this problem? Is there any approach how to avoid this?

Javers dependency in `javers-spring-5.1.3.pom`:

```
  <groupId>org.javers</groupId>
  <artifactId>javers-core</artifactId>
  <version>5.1.3</version>
  <scope>compile</scope>
```

Classgraph dependency in `javers-core.5.1.3.pom`:

```
<groupId>io.github.classgraph</groupId>
<artifactId>classgraph</artifactId>
<version>4.4.12</version>
<name>ClassGraph</name>
```

Comment: Could you give more details about the issue?
They claim to be compatible with JDK 8 see https://github.com/classgraph/classgraph

Comment: hi thanks for answering :) yes it's compatible and working now - as far as I remember the problem was not the Javers library but my Maven config stuff - unfortunately now I'm not able to reproduce :(

Comment: ClassGraph only requires JDK 7.

Comment: @LukeHutchison you are adding META-INF/versions/9/module-info.class to your jars. Seems legit but might cause errors on some outdated appservers like JBoss.

Comment: see https://issues.jboss.org/browse/JBEAP-15716?_sscc=t

Comment: Yes, I have seen this reported before elsewhere. But actually since old (pre-JDK9) classfile scanners should never be looking inside `META-INF` for classes in the first place, then putting `module-info.class` in a multirelease versioned section of a jar and compiling all the other classes for JDK 7 or JDK 8 is accepted as the most robust way to support both the module path on JDK9+ and the classical classpath on JDK 7/8. It is only an older classpath scanner that indiscriminately tries to parse classfiles of unsupported future version number, and in invalid locations, that will fail.

Comment: @BartekWalacik actually this is not just a ClassGraph problem -- it is becoming increasingly common now to provide a `module-info.class` now, usually in the root of the jar, and this is causing old runtime environments to crash. Really the best thing to do is upgrade your runtime environment. If you can't do that, you can force Maven to ignore the ASM version in your transitive dependencies, and forcibly depend upon a newer version (it is usually an old ASM dependency that causes the problem).