# Java 9 required for Javers 5.6.3?

Tags: java, wildfly-10, javers

I'm getting the deployment error below after I included javers 5.6.3 in pom. I'm using java 8 and Wildfly 10. Based on the documentation of Javers, it seems to me that Java 8 is compatible javers 5.6.3, hence I'm confused.
 POM:

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.javers</groupId>
    <artifactId>javers-core</artifactId>
    <version>5.6.3</version>
</dependency>
```

Server error:

> [org.jboss.as.server.deployment] (MSC service thread 1-3) WFLYSRV0003:
>   Could not index class META-INF/versions/9/module-info.class at
>   /content/myproject.war/WEB-INF/lib/classgraph-4.8.43.jar:
>   java.lang.IllegalStateException: Unknown tag! pos=3 poolCount = 18
>       at org.jboss.jandex.Indexer.processConstantPool(Indexer.java:1416)
>       at org.jboss.jandex.Indexer.index(Indexer.java:1450)
>       at org.jboss.as.server.deployment.annotation.ResourceRootIndexer.indexResourceRoot(ResourceRootIndexer.java:99)
>       at org.jboss.as.server.deployment.annotation.AnnotationIndexProcessor.deploy(AnnotationIndexProcessor.java:51)
>       at org.jboss.as.server.deployment.DeploymentUnitPhaseService.start(DeploymentUnitPhaseService.java:147)
>       at org.jboss.msc.service.ServiceControllerImpl$StartTask.startService(ServiceControllerImpl.java:1948)
>       at org.jboss.msc.service.ServiceControllerImpl$StartTask.run(ServiceControllerImpl.java:1881)
>       at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1149)
>       at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:624)
>       at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)

Similar issue was posted but no answer in [Classgraph dependency on Javers require JDK9+](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55180234/classgraph-dependency-on-javers-require-jdk9)

Comment: Looks like a problem with JBoss or your JVM implementation.
As far as I know, If you are running JVM 8 - it should ignore the META-INF/versions/9/module-info.class

Comment: See https://issues.jboss.org/browse/JBEAP-15716?_sscc=t